# How to I search using Google Drive API using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-api, google-drive-api

I am currently working with Google Drive API and search files.

```
 var test = false;

    gapi.client.drive.files.list({
      pageSize: x,
      q: "starred = test and viewedByMeTime > '2016-06-01T12:00:00-08:00', and not 'testemail@gmail.com' in writers",
      orderBy: 'viewedByMeTime desc',
      spaces: 'drive',
      fields: "nextPageToken, files(id, name, viewedByMeTime, mimeType)",
     }

    )
```

The issue I am having is that I want to be able to set var test = to false or true depending on whats the user selected. However, I can't put variable test in the parameter for it to work. How do I make it so starred = test will mean the same thing as starred = false?

I've tried:

```
q: "starred = '"+test+"' and viewedByMeTime > '2016-06-01T12:00:00-08:00' and not 'testemail@gmail.com' in writers",
```

but it also doesnt seem to work. Help would be much appreciated.

Also, any good guides on Google Drive API and javascript would help too! Thanks!

**Edit #1:** Additionally, how can I set viewByMeTime and in writers to variables as well? Do I change it to

```
viewedByMeTime > "'+variable+'" and not "'+variable+'" in writers?
```

How do I set the variables for dates and collections?

Comment: [*Google Drive API documentation*](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=google+drive+api+documentation&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&safe=active&gws_rd=cr&ei=lxnCWKnmGeeN0gLppob4Cg).

Answer (score 0):

Starred should be a boolean, not a string. Try removing your inner quotes.

`q: "starred = "+test+" and viewedByMeTime > '2016-06-01T12:00:00-08:00' and not 'testemail@gmail.com' in writers",`

Comment: Thanks! Can you also help me with the other variables for string and collection? Thanks again!