# How do I add to the date while converting to ISO?

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to get the date to convert to ISO time of half of a year ago, additionally, how can I change it to ISO time while losing the .milisecondZ at the end?

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toISOString();
var n = (n.addDays(-180))
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [*Add +1 to current date*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989382/add-1-to-current-date). Trimming the string is pretty simple too.

Comment: @RobG, Alright thanks! Can you also help me set the variables for date and collection here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42687476/how-to-i-search-using-google-drive-api-using-javascript